# Android - Google Server Side InApp Purchases verification Backend Error 500

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, server-side-validation

During the integration of G+ account I have turned off Google Play Android Developer API in Google Developer console by mistake. Google server started to return error:

**Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project**

So I again turned Google Play Android Developer API on, but Google server still returns

```
error:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Request I'm using looks like:
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/...
Everything before i turn off that switch was working correctly.

really appreciate any help / hint / idea.

Comment: Same problem here since sunday. All items can not be verified through google and thus not purchased by the user. Same here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/coH355N6D3Q%5B1-25-true%5D and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471836/inapppurchases-get-api-query-failed-code400-messageinvalid-value-code