# Inapppurchases: get api query failed "code":400,"message":"Invalid Value" "code":500,"message":null

Tags: google-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I get access_token by this way :https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

1.use google account allow acess get code

2.use code to get refresh_token

3.use refresh_token get access_token

when use this api

```
$url_purchase = "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications".
                "/$packageName/inapp/$productId/purchases/$token?access_token=".
                $return_data->access_token;
$return_purchase = http_get($url_purchase);
```

some billing return

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":null}}
```

some billing return

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"Invalid Value"}],"code":400,"message":"Invalid Value"}}
```

but some billing can success return

```
{"kind":"androidpublisher#inappPurchase","purchaseTime":"1395035642794","purchaseState":0,"consumptionState":1}
```

I think the access_token is right, why some billing failed . someone can help me ?thanks very much.

Are there any other way to check billing valid on the server?

Comment: Currently, some users using the the publisher verification got the error code 500 since sunday. There is no reaction from google, yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462051/android-google-server-side-inapp-purchases-verification-backend-error-500 https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/coH355N6D3Q%5B1-25-true%5D